# Is there a difference between IFS= and IFS='' in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell

This is a really simple bash question. I just wanted to know if there's any difference between `IFS=` and `IFS=''`.

Comment: One is arguably more readable.  Which one that is, however, is debatable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is not. They both set `IFS` to an empty value.

Answer (score 1):

No, since the shell before executing, performs *quote removal*. This turns `IFS=''` (or `IFS=""`) into `IFS=` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.  Is the second string actually the string `4946 533d 2727`, or is it `4946 533d 2701 27`?  Both strings will render as `IFS=''`, but the second one does not assign the null string to IFS.  If nothing nefarious is going on, then the string that you see as `IFS=''` is probably just the string `4946 533d 2727`, but you need to be careful.

Comment: I don't understand this `4946 533d 2727` `4946 533d 2701 ` thingy, what do you mean by those?

Comment: @ruohola That is a hex dump of the string.  I'm bringing up the issue of non-printable characters being in the string.  Note that those same non-printable characters can also be in the string without quotes, and this is (probably) a non-issue, but if you are executing untrusted shell code (it seems to be a popular workflow these days to do `curl ... | sh` and run other people's scripts to install things locally, which seems like a security disaster waiting to happen), it is something to have in the back of your mind.